# Retrieving data from nested JSON arrays

Tags: json, vb6

I'm trying to read a JSON string from an external source.  Here is the string -

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "params": {
        "timing": {
          "timing_matched_pairs": {
            "11": {
              "store_id": "12345",
              "date": "2015-03-15",
              "menuboard_time": "2015-03-15 16:54:08",
              "menuboard_duration": 10,
              "pickup_time": "2015-03-15 16:54:27",
              "pickup_duration": 10,
              "total_duration": 29
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "error_num": 0,
    "error_message": ""
  }
}
```

I am able to code and retrieve the response string for an error, which is this code with the "data" portion set to NULL.  My specific problem seems to be with the timing _matched_pairs array.  Each row should be an ID and a object containing the detail.  ( pair "11" contains storied 12345, date, etc)

I'm using this test simulate getting the JSON from a site -

```
Dim testJson As String = "{'jsonrpc':'2.0','id':1,'result':{'success':true,'data':{'params':{'timing':{'timing_matched_pairs':{'11':{'store_id':'12345','date':'2015-03-15','menuboard_time':'2015-03-1516:54:08','menuboard_duration':10,'pickup_time':'2015-03-15 16:54:27','pickup_duration':10,'total_duration':29}}}}},'error_num':0,'error_message':''}}"
Dim myObj As New dtd_Msg
myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of dtd_Msg)(testJson)
```

I can use the following to see some of the data -

```
appMsgBox.AppendText("JsonRPC: " & myObj.jsonrpc & vbCrLf)
appMsgBox.AppendText("ID:      " & myObj.id & vbCrLf)
appMsgBox.AppendText("Result.success:   " & myObj.result.success & vbCrLf)
```

Problem:  How do I access the data from "timing_matched_pairs" forward?

Below is my class for the JSON data

```
Public Class dtd_Msg
    Public Property jsonrpc As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property result As dtd_Result

End Class

Public Class dtd_Result
    Public Property success As Boolean
    'Public Property data As Object
    Public Property data As dtd_Data
    Public Property error_num As Integer
    Public Property error_message As String
End Class

Public Class dtd_Data
    Public Property params As dtd_Timing
End Class

Public Class dtd_Timing
    Public Property timing_matched_pairs As dtd_MatchedPairs
End Class

Public Class dtd_MatchedPairs
    Public Property uid As Integer
    Public Property readings As List(Of dtd_Readings)
End Class

Public Class dtd_Readings
    Public Property store_id As String
    Public Property evtdate As String
    Public Property menuboard_time As String
    Public Property menuboard_duration As Integer
    Public Property pickup_time As String
    Public Property pickup_duration As Integer
    Public Property total_duration As Integer

End Class
```

Comment: Smells like VB.Net, not VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Created class for timing_matched_pair using Dictionary

```html
    Public Class dtd_Timing
        Public Property timing_matched_pairs As Dictionary(Of String,Object)
    End Class
```

I then parsed that portion of the Json into a new object and loaded a list with the dictionary keys

```html
        myDictionary = myObj.result.data.params.timing.timing_matched_pairs

        Dim list As New List(Of String)(myDictionary.Keys)
```

From there is was easy to iterate thru the keys, parse the corresponding object and get the data.

```html
   myJson = JObject.Parse(myDictionary.Item(str).ToString)
   appMsgBox.AppendText(myJson.SelectToken("store_id").ToString & vbCrLf)
   appMsgBox.AppendText(myJson.SelectToken("date").ToString & vbCrLf)
```

Then was able load the keys into a list